# How to add group based filter for many2one field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-9

In my custom module i have two groups user and manager. Based on the group there are mutliple users. I have two may2one field both referring to res.users. In one field i need to show users associated with user group and in one field i need to show users associated with manager group. How can i filter the many2one fields

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use domain in field declaration:

```
myfield = fields.Many2one("res.partner", domain=[('mygroup', '=', 'yourgroup')])
```

Comment: We can't directly specify the groups in domain filter

Comment: Did you checked this solution?

Answer (score 0):

my_user = fields.Many2one('res.users',string='partner')
In XML

< field name="myuser" required="True" groups="group_manager"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use [lambda](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/sale/models/sale_order.py#L190) function.

```
users_1 = fields.Many2one('res.users', domain=lambda self: [('groups_id', 'in', self.env.ref('project.group_project_user').id)])
users_2 = fields.Many2one('res.users', domain=lambda self: [('groups_id', 'in', self.env.ref('project.group_project_manager').id)])
```